# Difference between the thread creation phenomenas and starting them

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

What is the Difference between the two thread creations in the code below:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread 
{
    int a=0;

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Some Thread");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        MyThread m=new  MyThread();

        Thread t=new Thread(m);
        m.start();     //what is difference between this
        t.start();     //and this

    }   
}
```

Both are giving me the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created

```
Thread t = new Thread();
```

Then the run method would not do anything as `Thread`'s run method is

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

where the target is null.
If you pass a target

```
Thread t = new Thread(target)
```

then thread would execute the target's run method.

If you have extended `MyThread` then `run` method in `MyThread` would execute

Comment: In your first case **Thread t = new Thread();** you are missing the **m** in the paranthesis, as in the question

Comment: I was trying to explain what happens when you have no target thread passed. If you do not pass any argument then `t.target` would be `null` and the `t.run` method would have executed nothing. But when you pass `MyThread m` then `t.target` would be `m` and it would execute `m.run()`

Answer (score 3):

The thread instance would be of different type in the two cases - `MyThread` vs. `Thread` - but the `run` method to be executed when you start the threads would be the same.

When you create a `Thread` with `new Thread(m)`, you don't have to pass a `Thread` instance. You merely have to pass an instance implementing the `Runnable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

It is eventually the same behavior.

`Thread` implements `Runnable` and `Thread` has constructor that takes a `Runnable`. Therefore `new Thread(m);` uses the `Runnable` implementation of its argument. But eventually the same `run` method is used, only the `Thread` instances are different.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to pass a Runnable implementations to a Thread and start it as a Thread, but in your example it just uses some extra CPU time. It would make sense to use in a situation like the one below.

```
class MyClass extends OtherClass implements Runnable { .. }

MyClass mm = new MyClass(..);
Thread t = new Thread(mm);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a Runnable object into the Thread(r) constructor, the Runnable becomes the thread's *delegate*.  These days, delegation is considered to be a more powerful, more flexible way to organize a program than inheritance.  That's especially true in Java where there is no multiple inheritance.

When you give the thread a delegate, the delegate can also inherit from some other class (as shown in user2794960's example).  But if you make your "thread" class inherit from Thread, then it can't also inherit from any other.

You know you're dealing with delegation when you say Foo *has* a Bar instead of saying Foo *is* a Bar.

Comment: **as shown in user2794960's example?** where is that?

Comment: Hmm...  It _was_ an answer to this question, but it seems to have been deleted.  I don't know why, it looked OK to me.  It showed an example of some `class Foo extends Bar implements Runnable`.  My point is, you can do that, but the language will _not_ let you say `class Foo extends Bar, Thread`.